# How to change a property attached to the whole graph

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Does anyone know how to change graph property "Norm". A command;

```
G = SetProperty[G, "GraphProperties" -> {"Norm" -> 1}]
```

doesn't work as I expected. Here is the graph constructor;

```
G = Graph[{Property[1, "Potential" -> 11],2,3,4},
          {Property[2 -> 1, "PreferenceIntensity" -> 5], 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 1 -> 4},
          EdgeWeight -> {5, 3, 4, 2},
          Properties -> {"GraphProperties" -> {"Norm" -> 5}},
          VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10] ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
In[1]:= g = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, 
    Properties -> {"GraphProperties" -> {"Norm" -> 1}}];
g2 = SetProperty[g, Properties -> {"GraphProperties" -> {"Norm" -> 5}}];
PropertyValue[#, "Norm"] & /@ {g, g2}


Out[1]= {1, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
Graph[G, Properties -> {"GraphProperties" -> {"Norm" -> 1}}]
```

Generally you should avoid creating symbol names that start with a capital letter, so use `g` in the future.